# D3 Bollinger Band Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to generate bollinger band using D3 library. I tried following code but unfortunately its throwing following error -

> VM224 d3.v3.js:670 Error:  attribute d: Expected number,
>   "M0,NaNL890,NaN"

What could be the cause of this error?

Code -

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var n = 20; // n-period of moving average
var k = 2; // k times n-period standard deviation above/below moving average

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(3, 0);
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });
var ma = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.ma);
  });
var lowBand = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.low);
  });
var highBand = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.high);
  });
var bandsArea = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return y(d.low);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.high);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
  [
    "9/9/2012",
    1000
  ],
  [
    "9/14/2013",
    100
  ]
];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d[0]);
  d.close = parseInt(d[1]);

  var bandsData = getBollingerBands(n, k, data);

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([d3.min(bandsData, function(d) {
      return d.low;
    }),
    d3.max(bandsData, function(d) {
      return d.high;
    })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(bandsData)
    .attr("class", "area bands")
    .attr("d", bandsArea);
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(bandsData)
    .attr("class", "line bands")
    .attr("d", lowBand);
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(bandsData)
    .attr("class", "line bands")
    .attr("d", highBand);
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(bandsData)
    .attr("class", "line ma bands")
    .attr("d", ma);

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
});

function getBollingerBands(n, k, data) {
  var bands = []; //{ ma: 0, low: 0, high: 0 }
  for (var i = n - 1, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var slice = data.slice(i + 1 - n, i);
    var mean = d3.mean(slice, function(d) {
      return d.close;
    });
    var stdDev = Math.sqrt(d3.mean(slice.map(function(d) {
      return Math.pow(d.close - mean, 2);
    })));
    bands.push({
      date: data[i].date,
      ma: mean,
      low: mean - (k * stdDev),
      high: mean + (k * stdDev)
    });
  }
  return bands;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amk1a2rc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amk1a2rc/1/)

First problem was, this being Bollinger Bands, that it needed more than the 2 data points you supplied it. When passing `n=20` to `getBollingerBands()` it means it'll want to extract a mean value out of 20 consecutive data points. Since there were only 2, it yielded a blank array, which in turn caused `NaN` values to make it into the `<path>`.

I updated that data array to be a whole lot longer, as needed.

The other issue was that instead of this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d[0]);
  d.close = parseInt(d[1]);
})
```

you had the function passed to `forEach` extend all the way down to include all the rendering code (eg `svg.append("path")`), which meant it was trying to render the whole thing one per data point (i.e. potentially hundreds of times).